# How to display current time in Notepad++ console dialog?

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to display the current timestamp in the console dialog of Notepad++.

If I give the command in the `Execute...` dialog

```
echo %time%
```

I get

```
%time%
================ READY ================
```

and the current time is not being displayed like it would in the cmd prompt.

Does anyone know how to get the time printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
cmd /c echo %time%
```

that should do the trick.

Some background information: `echo` is a build-in command of the windows command shell `cmd`, not an executable, so you cannot run it directly by Notepad++. But `cmd` has a command line option /c where you can pass build-ins as a parameter, to let the command shell execute them for you. The @ sign is only understood within the command shell, too.

Comment: Yes this has worked fine. If I add `@echo off` I get this error

CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Marking this as answer as it is working for me.

Comment: @Kishor: see my edit.

Comment: I understand now. I tried doing: `cmd /c @echo off` but it did not work. I will do just fine without it. Thanks